# Retrive randomly generated session id coockie name asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I want to change asp.net `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie name with some randomly generated string and also hash it's value. I've done both, But the problem is that i don't know how to get the `ASP.NET_SessionId and check if the hashed value is valid or not. The purpose is to prevent session hijacking.

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<Identity.ApplicationUserManager, DatabaseHelper.DatabaseModels.User>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            CookieName = Utility.Globals.GenrateRandomString(10),
        });
```

This is how i change `ASP.NET_SessionId'. I also check hashed value with below code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check If it is a new session or not , if not then do the further checks
        if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null && Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value != null)
        {
            string newSessionID = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Value;
            //Check the valid length of your Generated Session ID
            if (newSessionID.Length <= 24)
            {
                //Log the attack details here
                Response.Cookies["TriedTohack"].Value = "True";
                throw new HttpException("Invalid Request");
            }

            //Genrate Hash key for this User,Browser and machine and match with the Entered NewSessionID
            if (GenerateHashKey() != newSessionID.Substring(24))
            {
                //Log the attack details here
                Response.Cookies["TriedTohack"].Value = "True";
                throw new HttpException("Invalid Request");
            }

            //Use the default one so application will work as usual//ASP.NET_SessionId
            Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value.Substring(0, 24);
        }

    }
```

Comment: FYI - [You cannot directly modify a cookie. Instead, changing a cookie consists of creating a new cookie with new values and then sending the cookie to the browser to overwrite the old version on the client.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx#sectionToggle11)

Comment: Session cookie name or Identity cookie name? those are different. Also if you put random string as a cookie name for your authentication, every time your application restarts it will assign a new name for a cookie and will log-out all currently logged in users. Also it will not save you from cookie hijacking. Are you sure this is what you want?